# Having an issue with order of operations in node.js function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, gdax-api

I have a function that's I would like to use to poll historical data beginning from the start of Ethereum trading on the gdax exchange to current.  I want the code to poll 100 results (max allowable at a time) insert results into mongodb, add 100, then repeat, until I've got all historical data.  However, what I've wrote is executing in a different order.  First it sums all numbers in the for next, then executes all the http authedclient requests (although it properly uses the variable adding 100 to each request), then drops all the data into mongodb.  The problem I'm having is by the time the data is inserted into the mongodb client, the connection is closed.  How can I get it to execute each operation in the order I want it to?  Pastebin posted below.  Note the code I use has changed significantly to accommodate other errors, changed the insert loop to insertMany but I can integrate suggestions properly if anyone can help.  Thanks in advance.
https://pastebin.com/1BHi9RQV

```
var i = 100;

for (; i < 18750000; ) {

    publicClient.getProductTrades({ after: i }, function (err, response, data) {

        if (err) {

            console.log(err);

            return;

        }

        MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {

            if (err) {

                console.log(err);

                return;

            }

            var myobj = { data };

            for (item in data) {

                db.collection("EthTest").insertOne(data[item], function (err, res) {

                    if (err) {

                        console.log(err);

                        return;

                    }

                });

                console.log(data[item].trade_id);

            }

            db.close();

        });

    });

    i = i + 100;

};
```

Also downloaded stack app to properly post link and code.  Mobile site didn't allow me to do that.  Sorry!

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself. Some people may not be able to access Pastebin, or the link may break. Read more about asking good questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I tried, I'll edit at home, on mobile and I Don't seem to have access to the code tool bar, nor can I hit Ctrl + k

Answer (score 1):

Don't put `db.close();` in your `for` loop. Only call it once all your inserts are completed.

If this order is really important (get 100 results, store them, and so on), I suggest you split this code in 2 functions that call each other.
Something like that:

```
var i = 100;
var mongo;

function getData() {
    publicClient.getProductTrades({ after: i }, function (err, response, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        i = i + 100;
        saveData(data);
    });
}

function saveData(data) {

    var keys = Object.keys(data);

    // loop through the data
    for (j = 0, end = keys.length; j < end; j++) {
        db.collection("EthTest").insertOne(data[item], function (err, res) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }

            console.log(data[item].trade_id);

            if (keys[j] === keys[keys.length-1]) {
                // last item in data was inserted
                if (i < 18750000) {
                    // get the next 100 results if there's any
                    getData();
                } else {
                    mongo.close();
                }
            }
        });
    };
}


MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    mongo = db;
    getData();
});
```

Or course I cannot test it for you, but I hope you get the idea.

The other option would be to separate your 2 async calls.
Have the first loop get all the data (100 at a time), store them in an array, and once that is done, loop through that array and insert the data in Mongo.

Comment: And as for the executed order?  Will this correct the order of operations as well?  I still want the code to execute the authedclient (publicclient) operation, then insert into DB, then add 100.  However the code is executing each command all at once.

Comment: With 2 loops and 2 async calls, it's normal to get confused. Let me think of a way to make it cleaner.

Comment: Appreciate it.  Thank you.

Comment: Looks like what I need.  Will test when I get home, and thank you for your time.  This is my first project with js, node, and mongodb so it's been a bit of trial and error.